# What is the term for the conceptual distance between ordered nodes?

Tags: terminology, ontology, trie, hamming-distance

What is the name for the ordered relation between nodes?

For example: A color ontology represented in a trie has ordered color objects such that the marginal node between yellow and blue is green, and node between blue and green is teal, etc. I called this indexical.

I found that the term indexical is owned by linguistics ([en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexicality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexicality)). I had used the term indexical in academic presentations with a civil engineering audience that has more of a computer science awareness than usual -- nobody questioned my definition.

Searching online I found 'edit distance' and 'ordered.' Neither has the meaning I want.

In my presentation, I use the spork, the spoon and fork, as an example of a marginal object that requires a new node between spoon and fork ([www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruJ76-o5lxU](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruJ76-o5lxU)).

A broad example: Take every product in a grocery store and line them up, arrange those items with a closeness that represents their similarity. So, oranges and apples will be closer together than beef and fish. Which will both be closer together than to paper towels.

EDIT1: Revised the examples to any position between two points.

EDIT2: Simplified question.

Comment: Are you talking about "[equidistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistant)"? I'm not exactly sure what facet of the situation you're asking about.. the equal distance between the nodes, or the fact that a node is between the other two? Or "hybrid"?

Comment: @TimS. My example is equidistant but it is not constrained to that -- it includes all possible indexical points between two points. For example the color teal -- closer to blue than green. Or a spoon with really really small forks. More that there is a spectrum of positions in relation to each other than the fact that a node is between the other two.

Comment: Sounds like [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) (interpolated nodes) may be what you're looking for?

Comment: @TimS. Interpolations looks like it is how the indexical position is estimated if it is not clear (index for color gradients are calculable but for degree of spoon/fork interpolation sounds right). It still does not capture the concept of indexicality.

Comment: @TimS. 'Semantic similarity' is the term for finding the smiliarity https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3603583/ I usually see this called the 'edit distance.' But I see the distinction for simply measuring the similarity between two 'clean' nodes. I want to know the term for predetermining the indexical spacing. I suppose the semantic similarity could define that space as an integer.

Comment: @forest.peterson, probably you shoud describe the notion you are talking about (you are looking a term for) using more or less formal notation. What the relation do you mean?

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thank you. We have a set of concept frames. Those frames have a relational distance from each other. The term for measuring that distance goes by different terms depending on the discipline such as edit distance and semantic similarity. These terms are for the measuring of the distance. I am looking for the term that there is a distance. I am settling on indexicality for that term. Indexicality means that the frame has features. This by itself shows there is a conceptual distance between the frames.

Comment: To clarify -- indexicality is not related to the CS concept of an index, this is not a question about a lookup table. Just had coffee with a CS colleague and had to wade through this.

Comment: @forest.peterson, unfortunately, I still can't understand, but possibly you are talking about something related to *intension* or *intensional difference*...

Comment: @Stanislav-kralin Thank you, this discussion gives me enough information to continue. It is not a.clear topic so it just means I need to add a paragraph, make a graphic, and name it.